# What is the difference between org.mozilla.firefox.BaseApp and org.mozilla.firefox on Flathub?

Tags: linux, software-installation, package-management, firefox, flatpak

Recently, I decided to try switching over from using system-installed applications to Flatpaks from Flathub. When installing Firefox, I was given the following option:

```
Similar refs found for ‘firefox’ in remote ‘flathub’ (system):

   1) app/org.mozilla.firefox.BaseApp/x86_64/20.08
   2) app/org.mozilla.firefox/x86_64/stable

Which do you want to use (0 to abort)? [0-2]:
```

I don't understand what the difference between these are, so unsure which to pick, and therefore my question is as follows: What is the difference between the Firefox suffixed with BaseApp and the one not suffixed with BaseApp from Flathub?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pick the second one (`org.mozilla.firefox`), `org.mozilla.firefox.BaseApp` is some build dependency of Firefox (from  [flathub/org.mozilla.firefox.BaseApp](https://github.com/flathub/org.mozilla.firefox.BaseApp/blob/master/flathub.json): *This is a build dependency of Firefox and not the app itself. You want to install org.mozilla.firefox instead.*).

It's usually better idea to use the full "path" when installing a flatpak, so for Firefox you should use `flatpak install flathub org.mozilla.firefox` (see [Firefox flathub page](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.mozilla.firefox) for more details).